# Unity IoC spending a lot of time in ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, ioc-container

We are using Unity as our IoC container in an MVC3 project.  We just installed dynatrace, and it is showing an inordinate amount of time spent in a FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents method, specifically in ReadDirectoryChangesW.  This seems to be contributing to bad performance.

Why on earth would Unity be monitoring the file system?

```
Here's the call stack:

ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction
  HttpServerUtility.Execute
    HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandler.Wrap
      UnityControllerFactory.CreateController
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch
          FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents
            UnsafeNativeMethods.ReadDirectoryChangesW
```

Here is the UnityControllerFactoryCode

```
        try
        {
            if (requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString()))
            {
                controllerName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"], controllerName);
            }

            controllerName = controllerName.ToLower();

            return _container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                IMyLogger logger = _container.Resolve<IMyLogger>();
                logger.Error(LogEventIdType.General, ex, "Is the '{0}' controller defined in the Unity Container via RegisterType (in lowercase) in UnityIocBootstrapConfigure?", new object[] {controllerName});
                throw;
            }             
        }
```

The logger logs to the Windows event log.

Comment: Hm, `XmlConfigurator` seems like a log4net thing. Are you using log4net? I think that is your culprit, not Unity.

Comment: Yes, that's where I've been looking.  We are using log4net, and it was logging to a file, so I figured that was the culprit, but even with the file appender commented out, those calls persist.

Comment: @vcsjones - you're right - log4net is configured with its own config file (vs. config in the web.config), so it's watching that file for changes.  If you could post your comment as an answer, I can give you credit - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace is pointing to `XmlConfigurator`, which is log4net. log4net stores its configuration in a separate file from the web.config, so it starts a File System Watcher to check if the file has changed to reconfigure itself.

It would seem that the culprit of your performance problems then is log4net, not Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Unity itself does no such thing. In fact, the stack trace isn't in the Unity code at all, it's inside the controller factory.

Whoever wrote that added the file system watcher. Which was pretty silly, since ASP. NET already watches web.config and restarts the appdomain if it changes.

Comment: I've added the controller factory CreateController code.  There is no file system watcher in this class.